# Microsoft SQL Server - Getting latest record for value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm very not SQL savvy at all but I've been tasked with putting together a report for CIS benchmark test scores. I need to get the most recent score for each system without duplicates.

The system_identifier table houses the system info fields; I'm grabbing the value type 1426 (hostname)

The test_result table contains the score and date fields.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT system_identifier.value AS [System Name], test_result.score + '%' AS [Most Recent Score], LEFT(MAX(test_result.upload_date), 10) AS [Test Date]
FROM system_identifier INNER JOIN test_result ON system_identifier.target_system_id = test_result.target_system_id
WHERE (system_identifier.type_id = 1426)
GROUP BY system_identifier.value, test_result.score
ORDER BY system_identifier.value
```

This is currently returning all records where the System Name + Score combination is unique.

```
System Name   Most Recent Score   Test Date
-----------   -----------------   ---------
system1       84                  2019-06-10
system1       87                  2019-08-24
system1       94                  2019-09-14
system2       78                  2019-07-22
system2       85                  2019-09-12
system3       65                  2019-05-23
system3       74                  2019-07-03
system3       81                  2019-08-09
system3       91                  2019-09-10
```

Here is what I need:

```
System Name   Most Recent Score   Test Date
-----------   -----------------   ---------
system1       94                  2019-09-14
system2       85                  2019-09-12
system3       91                  2019-09-10
```

I've tried researching this but I'm not sure how to frame my question for a search, so I thought I'd ask here since I can be more verbose with what I'm looking for.

Let me know if you need any more info.

**EDIT**
Neeraj's answer put me on the right track, so marking as the answer.

I ended up creating a view with the initial SELECT to put everything in one table called "merged." Then, I had success with this query (with some formatting to make it pretty):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
UPPER(merged.value) AS Hostname,
merged.score + '%' AS Score
LEFT(merged.upload_date,10) AS [Date Uploaded],
FROM dbo.merged
INNER JOIN (SELECT merged.value AS hostname, MAX(merged.upload_date) AS Uploaded
FROM dbo.merged
GROUP BY merged.value) t2
ON merged.value = t2.hostname
AND merged.upload_date = t2.Uploaded
WHERE merged.type_id = 1426
ORDER BY hostname
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use correlated subquery:

```
select t1.SystemName, t1.MostRecentScore, t1.TestDate
from myTable t1
where t1.TestDate =
(
select max(t2.TestDate)
from myTable t2
where t2.SystemName = t1.SystemName
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT System_Name,Most_Recent_Score,Test_Date
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY system_name ORDER BY test_date DESC) rn
    FROM mytable t
) x WHERE rn = 1
```

In the inner query, `ROW_NUMBER()` assigns a rank to each record within groups of records having the same system name, ordered by descending test date. Then the outer query selects the top record in each group.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ad8ad962e42706115b5d345f3d7083cd)**:

```
System_Name | Most_Recent_Score | Test_Date          
:---------- | ----------------: | :------------------
system1     |                94 | 14/09/2019 00:00:00
system2     |                85 | 12/09/2019 00:00:00
system3     |                91 | 10/09/2019 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a subquery as

```
WITH T AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM
  (
    VALUES
    ('system1', 84, '2019-06-10'),
    ('system1', 87, '2019-08-24'),
    ('system1', 94, '2019-09-14'),
    ('system2', 78, '2019-07-22'),
    ('system2', 85, '2019-09-12'),
    ('system3', 65, '2019-05-23'),
    ('system3', 74, '2019-07-03'),
    ('system3', 81, '2019-08-09'),
    ('system3', 91, '2019-09-10')
  ) T(SystemName, MostRecentScore, TestDate)
)
SELECT T.*
FROM T INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT SystemName,
         MAX(TestDate) TestDate
  FROM T
  GROUP BY SystemName
) TT ON T.SystemName = TT.SystemName 
        AND
        T.TestDate = TT.TestDate;
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1d2aed8cd05f7f1caf9c86e7d0015a47)**</kbd>